# Extremum values using Lagrange multiplier

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

Given $f(x,y) = 2x^2-8xy+9y^2$ on $x^2+y^2=1$

now I am stuck in solving equations

$2x - 4y + \lambda x = 0$

$-4x +  9y + y \lambda = 0$

how do I do ?

Comment: You forgot to add the condition $\frac{d}{d\lambda} g = 0$.

Comment: I do realise that this is a question about Lagrange multiplier extremalisation, but if you want an easier way to find a solution, substitute x by $\cos(\theta)$ and $y$ by $\sin(\theta)$ in $f(x,y)$ - you're trying to find a solution on the circle, after all. You only have to derive to $\theta$ afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix} x&y\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 2&-4\\-4&9\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$

The constraint tells us that $\|(x,y)\| = 1$

$f(x,y)$ will be maximized when $(x,y)$ fall on the largest eigenvector, and minimized when it falls on the smallest.

$\lambda^2 - 11\lambda + 2 = 0\\
\lambda = \frac {11 \pm \sqrt{113}}{8}$

Now, if you still want to use Lagrange multipliers...

$\lambda = \frac{4y-2x}{x}\\
\lambda = \frac{4x-9y}{y}\\
\frac{4x-9y}{y} =\frac{4y-2x}{x}\\
4x^2 - 7xy - 4y^2 = 0\\
x^2 + y^2 = 1\\
4 - 7xy - 8y^2 = 0\\
x = \frac {4-8y^2}{7y}\\
(\frac{4-8y^2}{7y})^2 +y^2 = 1\\
\frac{16-64y^2 + 64y^4}{49y^2} + y^2 = 1\\
113y^4 -113y^2 + 16 = 0\\
y^2 = \frac 12  \pm \frac{7}{2\sqrt{113}}$

$y = \sqrt{\frac 12 + \frac{7}{2\sqrt{113}}}, \sqrt{\frac 12 - \frac{7}{2\sqrt{113}}}$

And I am getting a little bit exhausted.  You can take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

Let $L(x,y,\lambda)=2x^2-8xy+9y^2+\lambda(x^2+y^2-1).$

Thus, in the critical point we obtain:
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}=0$$ and
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}=0$$ or
$$4x-8y+2\lambda x=0$$ and
$$18y-8x+2\lambda y=0$$ or
$$2xy-4y^2+\lambda xy=0$$ and
$$9xy-4x^2+\lambda xy=0,$$ which gives
$$2xy-4y^2=9xy-4x^2$$ or
$$4x^2-7xy-4y^2=0.$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: Your last equation ...how to solve that ?